# XSS in location.hash.match() function

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript

I was solving a [CTF](https://securityjunky.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/domxss2.html). Just reading the source code of the web page, I found a vulnerable piece of code:

```
 var r4c='(.*?)';
 var results = location.hash.match('token\\('+r4c+'\\);');
```

I am unable to match any string with `'token\\('+r4c+'\\);'` with any of my input. Can anyone help me to solve this CTF?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Could you develop a little and explain why you think thie piece of code is vulnerable and how you think it could be exploited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to say for certain without more context, but this code appears to be potentially vulnerable to a regular expression denial of service (ReDoS) attack. The regular expression `'token\\('+r4c+'\\);'` contains an unanchored wildcard (`.`), which means it can match any character zero or more times.

This can cause the regular expression engine to take a long time to evaluate, especially if the input string is long and complex. An attacker could potentially use this to their advantage by crafting a malicious input string that takes a very long time to evaluate, potentially causing a denial of service on the system running this code.

A small input string that matches the regular expressio could be `token(abc);`. This input string contains the string token`(` followed by any number of characters (`abc` in this case) followed by `);`, which matches the regular expression.

Here is a JS snippet:

```
var r4c='(.*?)';
var regex = new RegExp('token\\('+r4c+'\\);');
var input = 'token(abc);';
if (input.match(regex)) {
  console.log('Input matches the regular expression');
} else {
  console.log('Input does not match the regular expression');
}
```